# Angular HTTP Request returns error from server

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I have a registration from in my angular project which sends the new user's details to the server and 
should  get a response from it also, but instead it returns an error.

This is the registration service code:

```
const httpOptions = {
  headers: new HttpHeaders({
    "Content-Type": "application/json"
  })
};

@Injectable({
  providedIn: "root"
})
export class RegisterService {
  constructor(private http: HttpClient) {}

  addUser(user: registerForm): Observable<registerForm> {
    return this.http.post<registerForm>(
      `http://localhost:3000/users/register`,
      user,
      httpOptions
    );
  }
}
```

Registration ts file:

```
export class RegisterPageComponent implements OnInit {
constructor(private rs: RegisterService, private registerForm: FormBuilder) {
    this.form = this.registerForm.group({
      email: "",
      password: "",
      fname: "",
      lname: "",
      city: "",
      adress: ""
    });
  }

  ngOnInit() {}
  getErrorMessage() {
    return this.email.hasError("required")
      ? "You must enter a value"
      : this.email.hasError("email")
      ? "Not a valid email"
      : "";
  }

  handSubmit(val) {
    console.log(val);
    this.rs.addUser(val).subscribe(data => {
      console.log(data);
    });
  }
}
```

and that's the error I get:

```
HttpErrorResponse {headers: HttpHeaders, status: 500, statusText: "Internal Server Error", url: "http://localhost:3000/users/register", ok: false, …}
headers: HttpHeaders {normalizedNames: Map(0), lazyUpdate: null, lazyInit: ƒ}
status: 500
statusText: "Internal Server Error"
url: "http://localhost:3000/users/register"
ok: false
name: "HttpErrorResponse"
message: "Http failure response for http://localhost:3000/users/register: 500 Internal Server Error"
error: "levitomer1996@gmail.com is already taken by another user."
__proto__: HttpResponseBase
```

```
This is the error when status is 200:
HttpErrorResponse {headers: HttpHeaders, status: 200, statusText: "OK", url: "http://localhost:3000/users/register", ok: false, …}
headers: HttpHeaders {normalizedNames: Map(0), lazyUpdate: null, lazyInit: ƒ}
status: 200
statusText: "OK"
url: "http://localhost:3000/users/register"
ok: false
name: "HttpErrorResponse"
message: "Http failure during parsing for http://localhost:3000/users/register"
error: {error: SyntaxError: Unexpected token O in JSON at position 0 at JSON.parse (<anonymous>) at XML
```

Maybe I'm missing something? at past I used to send requests and get responses by Fetch, then and catch.
I can't understand where can I control the response from the server at the client side...

Comment: Change the `e-mail id` may be? the error message is pretty clear.

Answer (score 1):

The error code is 500, meaning that the error is actually server side. 
The error is:
levitomer1996@gmail.com is already taken by another user.

try registering with another email.
If that doesn't work, show us the backend registration code

Comment: ```HttpErrorResponse {headers: HttpHeaders, status: 200, statusText: "OK", url: "http://localhost:3000/users/register", ok: false, …}
headers: HttpHeaders {normalizedNames: Map(0), lazyUpdate: null, lazyInit: ƒ}
status: 200
statusText: "OK"
url: "http://localhost:3000/users/register"
ok: false
name: "HttpErrorResponse"
message: "Http failure during parsing for http://localhost:3000/users/register"
error: {error: SyntaxError: Unexpected token O in JSON at position 0 at JSON.parse (<anonymous>) at XML"  **This is the error it send when status is 200**

Comment: Ok perfect, now you got no error in your backend but the frontend is expecting a json response. Instead, your backend gave back something else. Can you check with the network tab in the developer tools of your browser what the response sent back by your backend server is?

Comment: it returned **XHR**

Comment: I need to see the content of the response in text format to help you further

Comment: it's actually only sends status of 200 by expressJS **res.sendStatus(200);** and If it's got error it's sends status of 500 with an error message **res.status(500).send(err);**